# Running ruby code on cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm new to cucumber and I just found out Before hooks.

I'm already doing this on minitest/spec.

I want to create a git repository before any scenario and destroy it after.

this is what I have:

```
Before do
    require 'tmpdir'
    @directory = Dir.mktmpdir('temp-repo')
    @orig_directory = Dir.pwd
    Dir.chdir(@directory)

        `git init`
        `touch dummy`
        `git add .`
        `git commit -m 'dummy commit'`      

end

After do
    Dir.chdir(@orig_directory)
    FileUtils.rmtree(@directory)
end
```

But when i run cucumber it fails with this message:

`Lexing error on line 6: '          @directory = Dir.mktmpdir('temp-repo')'`

I already looked into the wiki and some other questions here but can't figure out how to get that working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hooks should be registered in the support files (for example `features/support/env.rb`) not in your features.

It's stated in the second sentence of the [wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks).

Comment: For reference, a link to the cucumber [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, and sorry for such silly question. I guess I read too quickly that part.

Comment: Looks like the wiki documentation link is dead now.  Dunno if it just changed URLs, or if it's gone, but what I think the same basic content can be found at https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=ruby#hooks currently (at time of this comment, anyway).